# Delete some data on dataset C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dataset

I want to delete some data from the dataset not the whole row.

Ex:
NewsNo    |   RID   |   REMARKS 
              1         100   L1,R1,R2,R3

In here i want to delete L1 data only.

My Code

```
 DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
 ExcelAdapter.Fill(dSet);
 dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Delete(); //<-- It delete whole row.i just want to delete L1 only.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to do update of remarks column with the value that doesn't contain L1

Assuming that `L1` is a value that you are getting dynamically (for example as user input) I think it could be something like that :

```
var valToRemove = "L1"; //provided by user
var remarks = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REMARKS"];
var splittedRemarks = new List<string>(remarks.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
splittedRemarks.Remove(valToRemove); //If you need to remove all the L1 values use `RemoveAll` method instead
dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REMARKS"] = splittedRemarks.Join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to update data not delete it...:

```
dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REMARKS"] = "R1,R2,R3";
```

Answer (score 1):

you should update the value of cell (like you would do in a database). in your case the to remove L1 it would look something like this

```
dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i] = string.join(",",dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ToString().Split(',').RemoveAt(0));
```

Comment: What if `L1` is not the first? For example  `R1,R2,R3,L1`

Comment: @Gubr, are you sure there is a function `RemoveAt(index)` for string arrays ?

Comment: @AlexArt. You are right. The correct (and clear) way to do it is just to loop though the array, remove the unwanted values and then join them again.

Comment: @Noobie you are also right. there is no RemoveAt for string arrays. looping through the array should take care of that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
string str = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REMARKS"].toString();
dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REMARKS"] = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("L1"), 3);
```

Here, index of L1 is found and 3 characters are removed starting from that index.

Comment: Can corrupt the data for some inputs. For example for `L123,L1,R1,R2` After running `str.Remove(str.IndexOf("L1"), 3)` the value will be `3,L1,R1,R2`

Comment: Oops, sorry. Working on that. @AlexArt.

Comment: @TechGuy, this works only if there's no value greater than L9.